# How to sum instances string values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to sum up a column of string values and then divide the result with another column. This is what I've been trying:

```
SUM(COUNT(state)/(epaper_opens))
```

This give me the error "aggregations of aggregations not allowed"
Alternativly I've been trying to cast the column into numeric or float64 but I get "Invalid numeric value" & "Bad double value)

```
SUM(CAST(state AS float64))
```

Here's the full query:

```
SELECT 
       state, 
       epaper_opens,
       CAST(send_at AS date) AS Sent,
       date AS Date, 
       date_diff(Date, CAST(send_at AS date), day) as Days, 
       #SUM(CAST(state AS float64))
       #SUM(COUNT(state)/(epaper_opens))
FROM analytics.fct_notifications

LEFT JOIN analytics.fcts_customer_activity_agg
  ON fct_notifications.customer_id = fcts_customer_activity_agg.subscription_id

WHERE state NOT LIKE "unproce%"
  AND state NOT LIKE "cancel%"
  AND subject NOT LIKE "Test%"
  AND customer_status = "Aktiv"
  AND epaper_opens IS NOT NULL
  AND DATE >= DATE_SUB(CAST(send_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  AND DATE <= DATE_ADD(CAST(send_at AS date), INTERVAL 30 DAY)

GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Please include the full original query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `countif()`:

```
countif(state = <val1>) as num_val1,
countif(state = <val2>) as num_val2,
```

And so on.

Comment: That brings me a step further, but how do I aggregate those two? This is what it looks like now: https://imgur.com/a/fYQXFVR

Ideally I would want to sum up the result of those two columns and divide it with the Days column

Comment: @pam_param . . . You would use `+` and `/`.  Constructing an expression from these function calls should not be tricky.

Comment: Apologies if I'm asking too basic questions. I'm learning on the job. Thank you for your help.

Comment: we love helping people that are learning - just make sure to always provide as much context as possible to let people help you - awesome nickname btw